# Add a new language in N2CMS

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, localization, n2cms

I cant find how I add a new language in N2CMS, and the associate that language to my new Startpage.

I have check in the code, but nothing, also checked in DB

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement multilingual websites in N2CMS, perform following step

1. Under Root of your site, add node of type "language intersection"
2. Under Language Intersection node, add one StartPage that will represent one language
3. Use translations toolbar button to associate translations of same content